# Javascript include namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I've a file foo.js with a namespace like this:

```
// foo.js
const Foo = {

  hello: () => {
    console.log('Hello world!');
  }

}

module.exports = Foo
```

Now in my file imports.js i can do this:

```
// imports.js
global.Foo = require('./foo.js');
```

so in any js files I can call `Foo.hello();`

Now the question is: in a specific js file is there a way to call `hello()` without `Foo`, like `using namespace Foo` of C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use require('./foo.js').hello like this:

```
// In Imports.js
global.Hello = require('./foo.js').hello;
```

Or if you need to use other things in foo, just create an alias

```
global.Foo = require('./foo.js');
global.Hello = Foo.hello
```

Or if you want to use [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), import hello directly:

```
import {hello} from './foo.js'
```

Importing it can have space advantages if you're using [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) in a build step, because it doesn't have to include unused exports in your bundle.

Comment: Ok, thanks @james-kraus, but if namespace Foo has a lot of functions, I must import all one by one or I can import all in one shot?

Comment: You can either import all at once, or one at a time.